# Base change for the canonical derivation map

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

The following is a subquestion of a [unanswered question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2155172/meaning-of-mathrmd-b-a-otimes-1-in-ega-iv-and-pullback-of-connections) posted two days ago by some user in math.stackexchange (answer that question if you prefer).

For a (not necessarily cocartesian) commutative square of commutative rings,
$$\begin{array}{ccc}
A&\rightarrow&B\\\
\downarrow&&\downarrow\\\
A'&\rightarrow&B'
\end{array}$$
 in [EGA 0$_{IV}$20.5.4](http://archive.numdam.org/article/PMIHES_1964__20__5_0.pdf#page=129) there is a map written as $d_{B/A} \otimes 1: B' \to \Omega_{B/A} \otimes_BB'$, where $d_{B/A}: B \to \Omega_{B/A}$ is the canonical derivation. Since $d_{B/A}$ is not a $B$-module homomorphism, **how is this map defined?**

Comment: Well, $B'=B\otimes_B B'$ so $d_{B/A}\otimes 1$ makes sense.

Comment: @Matthieu Romagny Both $B$ and $\Omega_{B/A}$ are $B$-modules, bur the map $d_{B/A}: B \to \Omega_{B/A}$ is not of $B$-linear (only $A$-linear).

Comment: Let me mention - it might be a clue - that they say $d_{B/A}\otimes1$ (whatever it is) is $A'$-linear

Comment: But $A'$ is any ring "between" $A$ and $B'$. It can be $A'=B=B'$ and then they say that (if as I think in this case $d_{B/A}=d_{B/A}\otimes 1$) that $d_{B/A}$  is $B$-linear! The definition of $d_{B/A}\otimes 1$ only makes sense to me if $B'=B\otimes_AA'$.

Comment: Exactly. What you say shows (I believe) that it *cannot* be $A'$-linear.

Comment: I think this is a mistake in EGA, but one that seems to be harmless.  In the diagram 20.5.4.2, presumably the ring $B'$ in the lower left should be $B$, and the bottom horizontal arrow should be $v$.  All of this theory is reviewed in Illusie's "Complexe Cotangent et Deformations I", so you could double-check there.